# Case when, help required SQL

Tags: sql, ssms, case-when

I am trying to do a row count so that I can use it in reporting services. The code below is meaning for the rows to count up to 40 over and over but the count sometimes does not.

```
CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(Forsamling.forsamling, 
1,1) ORDER BY Forsamling.forsamling) % 40) = 0 THEN 40 ELSE (ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(Forsamling.forsamling, 1, 1) ORDER BY 
Forsamling.forsamling) % 40) END AS SubGroupNo
```

I am not the best at SQL CASE WHEN so any help is appreciated. The full code and some screenshots down below.

```
 SELECT Forsamling.Forsamling, Forsamling.ForsamlingsNamn, Forsamling.Kommun, kommun.Kommun, kommun.KommunNamn, kommun.Lan, Lan.LansNamn, Lan.LansSuffix, Pastorat.Pastorat, Lan.Lan, Forsamling.DatumIn, Lan.DatumIn, Pastorat.DatumIn, Forsamling.DatumAvr, Lan.DatumAvr, Pastorat.DatumAvr, kommun.DatumIn, kommun.DatumAvr,
     CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(Forsamling.forsamling, 1, 1)
     ORDER BY kommun.Lan, Forsamling.Kommun, Forsamling.Forsamling) % 40) = 0 THEN 40 ELSE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(Forsamling.forsamling, 1, 1)
     ORDER BY kommun.Lan, Forsamling.Kommun, Forsamling.Forsamling) % 40) END AS SubGroupNo
 
FROM  
     (Select Forsamling, ForsamlingsNamn, kommun, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan
     FrOM A_Forsamling F
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01'
     )AS Forsamling Cross Apply
     (Select KommunNamn, kommun, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan
     FrOM A_Kommun K
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01' And Forsamling.Lan = K.Lan ANd Forsamling.Kommun = k.Kommun
     )AS Kommun Cross Apply
     (Select forsamling, kommun, pastorat, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan
     FrOM A_Pastorat P
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01' And Forsamling.Lan = p.Lan ANd Forsamling.Kommun = p.Kommun AND forsamling.Forsamling = p.Forsamling
     )AS Pastorat Cross Apply
     (Select  pastorat, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan, LansNamn, LansSuffix
     FrOM A_Lan L
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01' And Kommun.Lan = L.Lan
     )AS Lan
     
ORDER BY kommun.Lan, Forsamling.Kommun, Forsamling.Forsamling
```

[Where the error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WAYr.png)

[Where the error occurs but every 50 rows instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Gk8.png)

It appears to be at the exact same spot O.O ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your query, you are using `SUBSTRING(Forsamling.forsamling, 1, 1)` to partition. changing it to `''` will fix the issue.

Also, you can get the expected result by changing it as

```
SubGroupNo=(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY '' ORDER BY kommun.Lan, Forsamling.Kommun, Forsamling.Forsamling)  - 1) % 40 + 1
```

Full query :

```
SELECT Forsamling.Forsamling, Forsamling.ForsamlingsNamn, Forsamling.Kommun, kommun.Kommun, kommun.KommunNamn, kommun.Lan, 
     Lan.LansNamn, Lan.LansSuffix, Pastorat.Pastorat, Lan.Lan, Forsamling.DatumIn, Lan.DatumIn, Pastorat.DatumIn, 
     Forsamling.DatumAvr, Lan.DatumAvr, Pastorat.DatumAvr, kommun.DatumIn, kommun.DatumAvr,
     SubGroupNo=(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY '' ORDER BY kommun.Lan, Forsamling.Kommun, Forsamling.Forsamling)  - 1) % 40 + 1

FROM  
     (Select Forsamling, ForsamlingsNamn, kommun, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan
     FrOM A_Forsamling F
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01'
     )AS Forsamling Cross Apply
     (Select KommunNamn, kommun, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan
     FrOM A_Kommun K
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01' And Forsamling.Lan = K.Lan ANd Forsamling.Kommun = k.Kommun
     )AS Kommun Cross Apply
     (Select forsamling, kommun, pastorat, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan
     FrOM A_Pastorat P
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01' And Forsamling.Lan = p.Lan ANd Forsamling.Kommun = p.Kommun AND forsamling.Forsamling = p.Forsamling
     )AS Pastorat Cross Apply
     (Select  pastorat, DatumIn, DatumAvr, Lan, LansNamn, LansSuffix
     FrOM A_Lan L
     Where (DatumAvr IS NULL OR DatumAvr > '2018-01-01') AND DatumIn <= '2018-01-01' And Kommun.Lan = L.Lan
     )AS Lan

ORDER BY kommun.Lan, Forsamling.Kommun, Forsamling.Forsamling
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried both your query and changed to ' ' in my old query and I can confirm both ways works.